# htaccess - 301 redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following htaccess code which redirects any URL containing `ar`,`cl`,`co`,`ec`,`mx`,`pe` or `ve` to the same URL but with `es` in it's place.

eg.  `www.website.com/co/page` becomes `www.website.com/es/page`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^/?ar/(.*)$ /es/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^/?cl/(.*)$ /es/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^/?co/(.*)$ /es/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^/?ec/(.*)$ /es/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^/?mx/(.*)$ /es/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^/?pe/(.*)$ /es/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^/?ve/(.*)$ /es/$1 [R,L]


</IfModule>
```

This works fine on my development server, but not on the live site.  Is there a setting somewhere that could prevent this code from running?

Comment: On live web server, Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: Yeah you're right, it's not enabled, thanks!